# Click-once SQL Server Express deployment

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, clickonce

We are developing a small application that needs to have a local database installed on each users computer that will then sync up to the main database, via web services etc...

Anyways when we deploy the application on the users computer we want to use clickonce deployment. Now I have used this before but not attaching a SQL Server database. I know you can go to prerequisites in clickonce properties and click SQL Server Express.

Now the question is, when you have created your `.mdf` database file including stored procedures and all - how do you get this attached and setup automatically in the local database that is just installed through clickonce?

Also once this is finished in the future we may want to run updates to the database on the clients machines. We would like to use clickonce for this to publish database updates. Obviously we don't want to overwrite the database and just publish the latest updates based on if they already have the database or not and what version they have.

How could this be achieved using clickonce? Thanks